# Multiple instances of same class in guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, constructor-injection

I have class called client.

```
@requiredconstructorargs
Class client {

  Invoker invoker;
  String URL:

}
```

Now what I want is to have two different instances of client that will have different url.

Basic guice instance was

```
Client client(invoker){
  Return new client(invoker,hardcodedufl)
}
```

Invoker is another guice injection.

I want another instance with different url.

I tried `@named` and `bind(client.class).annotatedwith(Names.named("some value")).toinstance(client1(??))`
But was unable to pass the invoker.

Can somebody help ??

Comment: This question is far from syntactic Java. Can you please fix it up to make it easier to understand where your problem is?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Create this method inside your module class

```
@Named("primaryClient")
@Provides
public Client primaryClient(Invoker invoker) {
    return new Client(invoker, "hard coded url");
}
```

and then you can inject your Client like this:

`public void someMethod(@Named("primaryClient") Client client)`

Comment: I had issues using @named, eventually I used a list of objects and created 2 instances in the list. Referenced the list elements wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

I Created a list of client.

List listOfClient(invoker){

Client client1 = new Client(invoker, URL1);

Client client2 = new Client(invoker, URL2);

return Arrays.asList(client1,client2);

}

and referenced the list wherever needed.